# Iterating months and days in two different select/option

Tags: javascript, html-select

Basically, I'm trying to have one select element iterate the twelve months of the year, and depending on the month that is shown, for another select element to display the number of days in that month. 
i.e. If January is chosen in the first select element, then the second select element will display the days 1 to 30. If November is chosen then the second select element will display days 1 to 31 instead and so on.

HTML:

```
<select type="text" id="month"></select>

<label>Days:</label>
<select type="text" id="day" onchange="checkMonth(this.value)"></select>
```

Variables:

```
var months  =["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"];
var month   = document.getElementById('month');
var day     = document.getElementById('day');
```

JavaScript:

```
for(var index in month) {
    month.options[month.options.length] = new Option(month[index], index);
}

if (month.val() === months[3] || months[5] || months[8] || months[10]){
    var numOfDays = 30;

    for(var i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
        for(i in day) {
            day.options[day.options.length] = new Option(day[i], i);
        }
    }
}
else if (month.val() === months[0] || months[2] || months[4] ||  months[6] || months[7] || months[9] || months[11]) {
    var numOfDays = 31;

    for(var i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
        for(i in day) {
            day.options[day.options.length] = new Option(day[i], i);
        }
    }
}
else {
    var numOfDays = 28;

    for(var i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
        for(i in day) {
            day.options[day.options.length] = new Option(day[i], i);
        }
    }
}
```

Questions: How do I do this and is my code wrong?

Comment: Nice way to ask for help asking your question. :) First of all, you have not asked a question. You have described a requirement. It's easier to read if you actually formulate a question, at least in my opinion. I am also curious to why you want to achieve this. There are so many great date picker plugins that you can use, which does all of this for you. Is there a specific reason why you want to do it manually?

Comment: use this type of button { } on and try to post code

Comment: btw I can't see your code... It requires a login.

Comment: No one here is going to register(!) on a third party site to check out your code. Edit your question so that it contains the code. Copy&paste it, mark it, and then use the code button.

Comment: jsfiddle.net is also an alternative, but note that code should always be displayed in the question itself no matter what. This is because stackoverflow should be a network of questions and answers who is independent of other sites. We want questions and answers that work in the future, even if code dump sites may be shut down. Adding code to a jsfiddle or similar, can work as a quick way to actually see output, and is therefor useful as an addition to posting the code in the question itself :)

Comment: I completely forgot that you needed an account to view code on c9. I apologize. @CBroe Your comment didn't really help but thanks. Updated the ask to include the questions as I have forgotten to include it.

Comment: @KjetilNordin My goal is to get the days and months added to a SQL database separately but I'm trying to get it to be working with the javascript first and then add in the PHP accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your javascript code is missing any event listeners. This means that your javascript is just executed once, and then it is dead code afterwards. The system can't automatically guess that you want some of the code to run, when one of the checkboxes is selected. You have to specify it. Trying to run the code in an onload state, can cause errors.

So step 1, is to wrap your update functionality for the day-selection box, in it's own function. Let's call it `function updateDays()` this should be added right before your first if-statement. Remember brackets!

Step 2 is to fix your population of the month-selection box. The months will never change, so I'd simply hard code them into the HTML, but for the sake of not changing your code more than neccessary, here is what you need to do:

- Let's look at the `for(var index in month)` first. I'm guessing that you want to iterate through the array of month names, and add them to the selection box as options. Here it seems like you have confused `month` with `months` though. replacing the variable names, gives you 12 options in the drop down, but they so far have no content. They do however have values from 0-11, which seems to match your expected values when finding the days.
- Once again, it seems like you have confused `month` with `months`. changing the variable name, now successfully populates the month-select:

incorrect line:

```
month.options[month.options.length] = new Option(month[index], index);
```

correct Line:

```
month.options[month.options.length] = new Option(months[index], index);
```

Step 3 is to let the system know to update the days-selection box, whenever there is a change in the month selection. To do this, we have to add a listener function, in this case a change-listener:

```
month.addEventListener('change', updateDays);
```

Of course we want the updateDays to run once in the beginning as well, when the drop down is set to January, so we call it once here as well:

```
updateDays();
```

Step 4 is fixing your updateDays()-function. It has several thing that you should improve, but I'll talk about the clear error you have made first:

```
if (month.val() === months[3] || months[5] || months[8] || months[10]){
```

first of all, I do not think you can retrieve the value simply by calling month.val(). Second of all, when you use the `OR` operator `||`, you should know that javascript does not work this way. To achieve what you want, you will have to have both side of the equal operator inbetween every OR operator. Sample:

```
value === check1 || check2 || check3 || check4 //wrong
value === check1 || value === check2 || value === check3 //correct
```

Your code simply checks once if the value is "APRIL". if it isn't, it simply checks if "JUNE" is true. Javascript is designed so that when checking a string like this, it returns true if it exists. In other words, your current functionality would ALWAYS return 30, because the string "JUNE" would always exist.

Step 5 is to fix the function populating the day-drop down. I must admit, I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do there, so I rewrote the whole thing. In the end, here is what your javascript code could look like:

```
var months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
var month = document.getElementById('month');
var day = document.getElementById('day');

for (var index in months) {
  month.options[month.options.length] = new Option(months[index], index);
}

month.addEventListener('change', updateDays);

updateDays();

function updateDays() {
  var month = document.getElementById('month');
  var value = month.options[month.selectedIndex].text;
  if (value === months[3] || value === months[5] || value === months[8] || value === months[10]) {
    var numOfDays = 30;
  } else if (value === months[0] || value === months[2] || value === months[4] || value === months[6] || value === months[7] || value === months[9] || value === months[11]) {
    var numOfDays = 31;
  } else {
    var numOfDays = 28;
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
    day.options[day.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
  }
}
```

Check this out, to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/o6n6k1s8/

**My hot tip for you as a developer, is to learn more about how to debug errors in your application. Even though there were a lot of different mistakes, most of them were very small, and you had the general idea right. If you learn how to find your own specific errors, you'll be a great programmer. Google topics like chrome inspector, or mozilla firebug.**

And good luck

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the most helpful answer so far! According to the jsfiddle though, it looks through the days 1-31 a couple of times. I'll try to decipher through it more. The event listener is new information to me, thank you. I'll look into everything some more.

Comment: Oh I've noticed that it does updates the option by just adding the days instead of overwriting but other than that, thank you very much for the explanation

Comment: Sorry if id had some mistakes :). I'll se if I can fix it, but I am a little swamped at this moment. Always a pleasure to see that someone learns some core concepts. This will make you more likely to ask more specific questions later on ;)

Comment: YABOI: I know it's been 6 years, but I've fixed the fact that the days just keep appending --> https://codepen.io/pksml/pen/wvQMgxM And thanks @jumps4fun for this excellent JS code.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I streamlined it by comparing indexes.

(Written for Modern Browsers)

I've put all the code in, if it's confusing I'll strip out what doesn't apply.
Just thought it may be useful.

```
// Populate the Date Search Select Inputs
const getWeek = () => {
  let now = new Date(), yearBegin = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0)
  return Math.ceil((((now.setHours(0,0,0,0) - yearBegin) / 86400000)-1)/7)
}

const dayfield = document.getElementById('searchDay')
const weekfield = document.getElementById('searchWeek')
const monthfield = document.getElementById('searchMonth')
const yearfield = document.getElementById('searchYear')
const today = new Date()
const months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

let numOfDays = 0
const updateDays = (value) => {
  if ([3,5,8,10].includes(value)) numOfDays = 30
  else if ([0,2,4,6,7,9,11].includes(value)) numOfDays = 31 
  else numOfDays = 28
};updateDays(months[today.getMonth()])

monthfield.addEventListener('change', () => {
  updateDays(monthfield.selectedIndex) // Update days compares the Months array index, with the select index.
  while (dayfield.options.length > 0) dayfield.remove(0)
  for ( let d = 1; d <= numOfDays; d++ ) dayfield.appendChild(new Option(d, d))
  dayfield.value = today.getDate()
})
dateBoxesPopulate = () => {
  
  for ( let y = 2000; y <= 2050; y++ ) yearfield.appendChild(new Option(y, y))
  yearfield.value = today.getFullYear()

  for ( let m = 0; m < 12; m++ ) monthfield.appendChild(new Option(months[m], months[m]))
  monthfield.value = months[today.getMonth()]

  for ( let w = 0; w <= 53; w++ ) weekfield.appendChild(new Option(w, w)) // Week One Starts On The First Sunday.
  weekfield.value = getWeek()

  for ( let d = 1; d <= numOfDays; d++ ) dayfield.appendChild(new Option(d, d))
  dayfield.value = today.getDate()
}
```